# ffmpeg function avcodec_receive_frame always return EAGAIN error

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I’m using ffmpeg to decode he-aac audio file on iOS，which decoder is `libfdk_aac`，here is the audio file: 
https://cdn.perterpon.com/listen/test/bbc.mp4
and here is the `av_dump_format` result:

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso6
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6dash
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 2 channels (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : USP Sound Handler
```

`av_read_frame` and `avcodec_send_packet` return 0, but `avcodec_receive_frame` always return `AVERROR(EAGAIN)`

I’v tried ffmpeg command line tool: `ffmpeg -i bbc.mp4 bbc.mp3`, it success, and the mp3 file is good to playback on iOS.

here is my code:

```
av_register_all();
AVFormatContext *avFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bbc" ofType:@"mp4"];

int ret;
ret = avformat_open_input(&avFormatContext, [filePath UTF8String], NULL, NULL);
if (0 != ret) {
    NSLog(@"avformat_open_input failed: %d", ret);
}

ret = avformat_find_stream_info(avFormatContext, NULL);
if (0 != ret) {
    NSLog(@"avformat_find_stream_info: %d", ret);
}

// the libfdk_aac decoder
AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("libfdk_aac");
AVCodecContext *codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

ret = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL);
if (0 != ret) {
    NSLog(@"avcodec_open2 faild: %d", ret);
}

AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
AVPacket packet;
av_init_packet(&packet);

// start read data and decode data
while (true) {
    ret = av_read_frame(avFormatContext, &packet);
    if (0 != ret) {
        break;
    }
    ret = avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, &packet);
    if (ret != 0) {
        NSLog(@"send package with error: %d", ret);
        continue;
        break;
    }
    while (true) {
        // the ret below is always return -35, means AVERROR(EAGAIN)
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(codecContext, frame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
            NSLog(@"avcodec_receive_frame with EAGAIN error: %d", ret);
            break;
        } else if (ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            NSLog(@"end of file");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

I'v tried replace `bbc.mp4` file to `bbc.mp3` file, and change the decoder to: `AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP3);`，all of the things working every good. Thank you very very very much.

Answer (score 1):

When avcodec_receive_frame returns EAGAIN, you must call avcodec_send_packet with more data (or a null packet at the end of the stream) before calling avcodec_receive_frame again.

Comment: I tried, when receive `AVERROR(EAGAIN)`, do `av_read_frame(avFormatContext, &packet);` and `avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, &packet);`，after this `avcodec_receive_frame(codecContext, frame);` always got `AVERROR(EAGAIN)`

Comment: This logic is already in the code, I think. May be I was wrong, haha

Comment: The inner while loop is an infinite loop. When EAGAIN is returned, it calls continue which continues the loop and you get EAGAIN. You will always get EAGAIN until the loop is broken (or removed)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, when I post this code, I did some edit, already update my code, the `continue` in the inner loop changes to `break`, the result is the same.